# Get Dropbox metadata in class attribute in async mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynchronous, dropbox, dropbox-api

I'm trying with the following code get metadata of `Dropbox dir`, calling `loadMetadata` `Dropbox API` and hope the `callback` (loadedMetadata) is called when data are in device. This is the code:

```
_semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void){
        NSLog(@"loadMetadata() in async block");

        [self.restClient loadMetadata:@"/"];
});


dispatch_semaphore_wait(_semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
```

As you can see, I'm calling in async mode, to get the metadata in one property and then return in other method. I'm make the following call in `loadedMetadata` callback:

```
    dispatch_semaphore_signal(_semaphore);
```

Good, the issue here is that `loadedMetadata` callback is never called. I don't know why, but the trace I put in `loadedMetadata` is never printed and `application is freeze` (waiting loadedMetadata signal). I put `DISPTACH_TIME_FOREVER` as example, please not what you have in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/start/ios:

> Make sure you call DBRestClient methods from the main thread or a
>   thread that has a run loop. Otherwise the delegate methods won't be
>   called.

You should call `loadMetadata` from the main thread. The actual operation is async already.

Comment: What is the API V2 version of this call?